# listen to event raised from application running in windows service

Tags: c#, events, windows-services

I am trying to listen to event which is raised from application running under a windows service. Below is sample code to demonstrate as what I am after ...

Separate Class library code(classlibrary1.dll)

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1 : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public event TestServiceDel TestEvent;

        TestEventArgs args1 = new TestEventArgs
        {
            Data = "Hello Buddy ... How Is Life!!!!!"
        };
        public void RaiseEvent()
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("TestService"))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("TestService", "Application");

            EventLog.WriteEntry("TestService","Before raising event ...");

            if (TestEvent != null)
                TestEvent(this, args1);

            EventLog.WriteEntry("TestService","After raising event ...");
        }
    }
```

Hosted Windows Service (windowsservice1exe)

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ClassLibrary1.Class1 cs = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
        cs.RaiseEvent();
     }
```

Client application (consoleapp1.exe)

```
class Program : MarshalByRefObject
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 cs = new Class1();
        cs.TestEvent += Cs_TestEvent;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Cs_TestEvent(object sender, TestEventArgs args)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("TestService",args.Data, EventLogEntryType.Information);
        Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
    }
```

As you can see, I have tried subclassing `MarshalByRefObject` for both publisher/subscriber but it's not working. I mean I can see in event log that the events are getting raised but my client application never receives the notification (or) the notification never reaches.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Since my service and client both running in same machine, I believe I don't need to use `Remoting`. Right?